# Adobe Caslon Pro apostophes and "e" letter issue with xelatex

Tags: xetex

For my thesis I'm using XeLaTex with Adobe Caslon Pro font 
Here is the part of the preamble

```
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\setdefaultlanguage{french} 
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,Mapping=tex-text]{Adobe Caslon Pro}
```

I don't know if it's an issue but after an "apostrophe" the letter "e" looks too near from the "apostrophe"

On the picture you can see in red that the letter "e" or "é" is really near from the apostrophe but not the letter "u" or "a" underline in blue.

[image: apostrophe e latex]

Any idea?

Thanks

P.-S. I just use latest miktex on win 7. And I do a classic compilation straight on the consol...

Comment: The problem is with the Abode font set – the apostrophes are definitely not kerned for French. Your file and distribution have nothing to do with it. To my knowledge, the only Adobe font that looks fine in French is Adobe Garamond Pro. But if someone has a quick LaTeX fix that does not involve creating a virtual font, that would be great.

Comment: Note, the "o" is also too close to the apostrophe (as are all letters even though it does not seem as shocking with an "a" or a "u").

Comment: Hum thank you for your information. However, I don't understand why this problem occurs with xelatex but not with Word or Illustrator for instance...

Comment: Yes, so am I, but it seems there is a recurrent problem with this font set, and apostrophes are part of it. They don't do very well with XeLaTeX at any rate, apparently because of messy OpenType features (there are several questions about selecting text with those fonts, for instance). Sorry I can't be more help, what I just meant is that it is a recurrent problem, and it probably comes from the font because XeLaTeX does perfectly well with other fonts like Junicode.

Comment: Does this problem continue to arise if you compile your document under lualatex instead of xelatex? Just curious.

Comment: I definitely think this is a font problem. In the “L’é” combination, the é is actually *closer* to the L than *without* the apostrophe (same with regular e) while for the other letters, there is space *added.* Confer [the image I prepared](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jtNxP.png). To me, this just seems like *unusual* kerning.

Comment: @brian-ammon thanks for the infos

Comment: @Mico Actually, I've never used lualatex. I've tried but I got error. I'll try it later and tell you if I stuceed...

Comment: @Swiss12000 You can't use `polyglossia` with LuaLaTeX  so you would need to load `babel` (and `fontspec`) instead to do the test.

Comment: @ienissei Please convert your comments to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the problem is with the Abode font set – the apostrophes are definitely not kerned for French. Your file and distribution have nothing to do with it. To my knowledge, the only Adobe font that looks fine in French is Adobe Garamond Pro.

XeLaTeX works perfectly well in French with other fonts that have better (more appropriate, at least) apostrophe kerning, so you should perhaps consider switching to one of these. I would suggest [Junicode](http://junicode.sourceforge.net/), which is free and has a huge character set. It is also based on fonts from the same time period as Caslon.