# Redefine apostrophes to prevent bad kerning

Tags: punctuation, unicode, kerning

The apostrophe in Adobe’s Minion Pro font has a kerning that is much too tight for typesetting French, where sequences of letters like **l’a** or **d’e** or **j'a** are common.

One solution I found is to wrap the apostrophe in a box, which prevents kerning with surrounding elements and gives a much nicer result:

[image]

(regular kerning is at the top, with my workaround below). I can redefine the “nice apostrophe”, a.k.a. U+2019, a.k.a. right single quotation mark, by the following command:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2019}{\mbox{'}}
```

However, this doesn't work for the regular ASCII apostrophe, U+0027. So, how do you suggest I change that (in a way that doesn't affect the working of `'` as a prime in math mode)? It would be an added bonus if the solution could avoid breaking hyphenation…

Comment: No, what the regular form does, is kerning (_without_ “bad”!). What you do, is preventing kerning at all! As far as I know, it would by the way enough to put the apostrophe into an own group – means put it in braces `{'}`.

Comment: I also suspect, with your approach you break the hyphenation algorithms of babel and polyglossia.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61759/adobe-caslon-pro-apostophes-and-e-letter-issue-with-xelatex . You might even want to switch your font.

Comment: Well, beauty is in the eye of the beholder but I find the first (default) version _much_ more beautiful than the second.

Comment: @cgnieder So do I but the French have a general fondness for spaces around punctuation. For example : like so !

Comment: @Christian I know :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package [minionpro](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/minionpro) has the optional argument `loosequotes` that may be to your help. See page 4 in the manual where the option is described:

> The quote signs of MinionPro are set rather tight. This can lead
>   to undesirable spacing for apostrophes. The loosequotes option
>   slightly increases the side bearings of quotes.
>   This option requires pdfTEX 1.40 and microtype 2.0. Beware
>   that this option prevents hyphenation of words containing apostrophes.
>   Such words will require explicit hyphenation commands `\-`

Another possible solution is to use the package [microtype](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) and the possibility to defined parameters for the `\SetExtraKerning`-command. Have a look at section 5.4 in the manual, where the author has defined a configuration for extra kerning to be used in French text.

```
\SetExtraKerning
   [ name     = frenchdefault,
     context  = french,
     unit     = space   ]
   { encoding = {OT1,T1,LY1} }
   {
     :  = {1000,}, % = \fontdimen2
     ;  = {500, }, % ~ \thinspace
     !  = {500, },
     ?  = {500, }
   }
```

See also page 22 (section 6) for the use of it, and especially at page 23, where the use of the command `\DeclareMicrotypeBabelHook` is described.

Comment: I already have the `loosequotes` option turned on, and it doesn't do enough… I'll try your microtype solution, though, which seems nice!

Answer (score 12):

I think that the best approach is to use the "real apostrophe" `’` in text, so the definition as `\mbox{'}` can coexist peacefully with the usage of `'` in math. Saying

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2019}{\mbox{'}\hskip 0pt \nobreak}
```

will allow hyphenation of the word following the apostrophe. However you'll miss the `''` ligature for closing double quotes.

Here's a code I wrote for a similar problem (see [this discussion on the GuIT forum](http://www.guitex.org/home/it/forum/5-tex-e-latex/51159-kerning-dellapostrofo-con-minionpro-e-titolo-section)):

```
\makeatletter
\edef\qu@te{\string'} % save a copy of the ordinary apostrophe
\catcode`'=\active    % make ' active

%%% Update \@resetactivechars (that shouldn't act on ' any more)
\begingroup
\obeylines\obeyspaces% 
\gdef\@resetactivechars{% 
\def^^M{\@activechar@info{EOL}\space}% 
\def {\@activechar@info{space}\space}% 
}% 
\endgroup

%%% In case hyperref is not used
\providecommand\texorpdfstring[2]{#1}

%%% Define the active '
\protected\def'{\texorpdfstring{\texqu@te}{\string'}}

\@ifpackagewith{inputenc}{utf8}
  {\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2019}{\texqu@te}}{}

\def\texqu@te{\relax
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter^\expandafter\bgroup\expandafter\prim@s
  \else
    \expandafter\futurelet\expandafter\@let@token\expandafter\qu@t@
  \fi}
\def\qu@t@{% 
  \ifx'\@let@token
    \qu@te\qu@te\expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    {}\qu@te{}\penalty\@M\hskip\expandafter\z@skip
  \fi}
\scantokens\expandafter{% 
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\pr@m@s\expandafter{\pr@m@s}}
\makeatother
```

In math mode `'` should have the same meaning as the math active, that is, `\active@math@prime` which means `^\bgroup\prim@s`; in text mode we have to check whether another apostrophe follows. I use `\futurelet` directly in order not to swallow spaces with `\@ifnextchar`.

If the apostrophe has to be set, I use `{}'{}` to defeat the kerning.

The final `\scantokens` is just to redefine `\pr@m@s` under the current catcode settings without copying its definition from the LaTeX kernel.

Answer (score 3):

Using XeTeX with Minion Pro and Kepler Std, I find more satisfying the space obtained replacing a line, in the above code, with the following one (with a different kerning, note the two \kern statements):

```
\def\qu@t@{% 
  \ifx'\@let@token
    \qu@te\qu@te\expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    {\kern0.08em}\qu@te{\kern0.01em}\penalty\@M\hskip\expandafter\z@skip
  \fi}
```

(of course, your mileage may vary).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Nice to see you here! Ciao!

Answer (score 0):

Using new versions of XeTeX, `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` (from `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`) may not be working at all, because `inputenc` package is ignored with utf8 based engines.

To solve the problem, you may use this code :

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{’}{\mbox{'}}
```