# MinionPro inconsistent space between letters separated with an apostrophe

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I'm writing a document with the MinionPro font from Adobe using `fontspec` and XeLaTeX. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\setmainfont{MinionPro-Regular}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    Y'en \\
    l'ensemble \\
    L'ensemble
\end{document}
```

Output: [image]

As you can see, in the first line, the space between `Y` and `en` is correct. Just above, `l` and `ensemble` are way too close between each other. It is even worst with a capital `L`. I can manage that with a `\hspace`, but is it a better, and more automatic way to handle this ?

For comparison, here is how it looks with the LaTeX default font:

[image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411846/xelatex-minion-pro-and-italian-apostrophe-kerning and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71335/redefine-apostrophes-to-prevent-bad-kerning

Comment: @UlrikeFischer For some reason, solutions found in theses links work in my MWE, but not in my report. Anyway I will look around with this. Thank you.

Comment: @Nakrule "For some reason, solutions found in th..." this is exactly what happened to me today. Totally other issue, but same symptom: solution works with MWE, but not in main document. The problem is elsewhere, and I am weary of looking for it...