# French spacing with xelatex and Minion Pro

Tags: spacing, xetex, fontspec

I've just installed the full version of MacTex 2014 on my MacBookpro running OSX 10.8.5, and I'm surprised by the output of this minimal document compiled with xelatex,

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
l'étranger, l'équipe
\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems to me that the spacing is wrong (the "l" and the following word are too close), or is it how it's supposed to look like with Minion Pro? Is there an option I've overlooked?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61759/7883

Comment: If `luatex` is an option for you, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3602/7883 on changing the kerning by writing a feature file.

Comment: alright, thanks for the pointers. A few different fonts I tried showed kerning problems with xelatex, I settled for Optima which looks OK. I did not try the luatex feature file, it sounds far too involved for a casual user like myself.

Comment: Can't fontspec modify kerning by itself?

Comment: @Bernard May be not font spec, but microtype?

Comment: Perhaps, but microtype doesn't fully work with XeTeX. Still I think it can be solved without the luatex engine, since the `MinionPro` package (for use with `pdflatex`) knows the problem and solves it. It ‘would be enough’ to slightly increase the side bearings of the apostrophe character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem affects most Adobe fonts (Adobe, are you listening?).  I don’t use `xetex` enough to know what can be done about it in `xetex`, but in `luatex` you can write a feature file to adjust the kerning without editing the font itself.  It’s much easier than it sounds.  E.g.,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents,fontspec,microtype}
\begin{filecontents*}{minion.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;

feature kern {
  pos \quoteright \a 10;
  pos \quoteright \eacute 10;
  pos \quoteright \o 10;
} kern;
\end{filecontents*}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}[
  FeatureFile={minion.fea}]
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
l’étranger

d’accord

d’ores et déjà
\end{document}
```

[image: output of sample code]

You just have to keep adding lines like `pos \quoteright \e 10;` until you’ve listed anything that may come after the apostrophe.  You can play with the value until you have it as tight or loose as you like:  1, 10, 20…

If you’re writing a bilingual document and the other language requires tighter kerning (off hand, I don’t know of one), you can specify to which language the features you define should apply.  That’s more work, but the technique is explained at [tex.stackexchange.com/a/142664/7883](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142664/7883).

UPDATE: Since version 2.7 of `luaotfload`, feature files are no longer supported.  See [tex.stackexchange.com/a/312160/7883](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312160/7883) for a new way to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the effort and worked example. I don't feel comfortable playing with kerning (I'm not a designer), so I'll stay away from those fonts (or french, when I can help it).

Answer (score 3):

I am currently disabling kerning between an apostrophe and a succeeding letter by using XeTeX's interchartoken mechanism:

```
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\newXeTeXintercharclass\ApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`'\ApostropheClass
\newXeTeXintercharclass\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`a\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`A\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`à\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`â\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`e\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`E\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`é\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`è\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`ê\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`i\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`o\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`ò\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`U\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`u\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`ù\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXcharclass`y\AfterApostropheClass
\XeTeXinterchartoks\ApostropheClass\AfterApostropheClass={\penalty\@M\hskip\z@}
```

I'm inserting glue rather than a kern, in order to avoid disabling hyphenation.  The penalty is there to inhibit a line break at the glue position.