# Lualatex and kerning with minion pro

Tags: luatex, miktex, kerning, minionpro

I'm trying to fix the kerning around the quote with a feature file. I looked at several answer and tried this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218415/french-spacing-with-xelatex-and-minion-pro):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents,fontspec,microtype}
\begin{filecontents*}{minion.fea}
   languagesystem DFLT dflt;
   languagesystem latn dflt;

feature kern {
  pos  \quoteright \a 40;
  pos \quoteright \eacute 10;
  pos \quoteright \o 10;
  pos \quoteright \e 8000;
 } kern;
\end{filecontents*}
\setmainfont{MinionPro-Regular}[
  FeatureFile={minion.fea},Path=fonts/]
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
l’étranger

d’accord

d’ores et déjà

L'e
\end{document}
```

It doesn't change the kerning

[image: bad kerning lualatex]

it's particulary bad with a "L".
Any tips ?

I'm using Miktex 2.9

Thank you

Edit:
Using the suggestion in comment

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents,fontspec,microtype}
\directlua{
fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
name = "ktest",
{
type = "kern",
data = {
["quoteright"] = { ["e"] =  50,
                   ["a"] =  50,
                   ["eacute"] =  50,
                   ["o"] =  50, },
}
},
"extra kerns"
}
}
\setmainfont{MinionPro-Regular}[
  RawFeature=+ktest,
  Path=fonts/]
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
l’étranger

d’accord

d’ores et déjà

L'e
\end{document}
```

[image: good kerning minion pro lualatex]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which version of LuaTeX do you use? (Version information should be at the top of the `log` file.)

Comment: Yes, we need version information. Feature files are no longer supported in the most recent `luatex`; see Ulrike’s answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312160/7883 for the new approach.

Comment: I'm using lualatex 0.95. This was the problem.
Thanks for pointing me to the answer. I modified my file and edited my question with a working example. Thank you.