# The apostrophe with Adobe Caslon Pro

Tags: fontspec

I'm writing an article with Adobe Caslon Pro and Xelatex and I found that this mark punctuation ’, an apostrophe, which is ordinary used in French, has not the required interval when used, for instance, in the following words : "L'écriture". This issue is probably similar to this one described here : [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218415/french-spacing-with-xelatex-and-minion-pro][1]
In this post, a solution consists in doing something I can't replicate. Could anyone help me to do that?
This is the MWE:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents,fontspec,microtype}
\begin{filecontents*}{minion.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;

feature kern {
  pos \quoteright \a 10;
  pos \quoteright \eacute 10;
  pos \quoteright \o 10;
} kern;
\end{filecontents*}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}[
  FeatureFile={minion.fea}]
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
l’étranger

d’accord

d’ores et déjà
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems `Libre Caslon` (open type name  `Libre Caslon Text`) has a better spacing for the apostrophe.

Comment: I already tested it. But it is not the same finish at all.

Comment: I agree that Libre Caslon isn’t as attractive. But have you tried the solution by jch in the linked question about Minion? This is a problem with Adobe fonts generally, and the same approaches should apply.

Comment: I've just edited my question in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t have Caslon, but this is a problem with many Adobe fonts, so I’ll illustrate an approach with Minion. Updating [French spacing with xelatex and Minion Pro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218438) in view of [How to adjust font features in LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312160/7883), we get something like this (iff you’re willing to change your compiler to `luatex`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec,microtype}
\directlua{fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature
  {
    name = "kern",
    type = "kern",
    data = {
      ["quoteright"] = { ["a"] = 150 , ["eacute"] = 150 , ["o"] = 150 },
    },
  }
}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\frenchspacing
\begin{document}
l’étranger

d’accord

d’ores et déjà
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Adjust `150` to taste.

Comment: Thanks! It works very well, but it means that I have to adjust an entire book on a case-by-case basis! For instance, these are my adjustments:  ["quoteright"] = { ["a"] = 50 , ["eacute"] = 150 , ["o"] = 90 , ["h"] = 90 , ["e"] = 90 , ["u"] = 50}

Comment: Yes, it’s painful — a sample of what type designers must go through when they kern a whole font family.

Comment: I can't manage to adjust ["ecirc"]. The space does not change. Any idea?

Comment: Did you mean `["ecircumflex"]`? Fontforge is useful for finding glyph names (and for many other things).

Comment: I'd like to add a space before "?". How to do that?

Comment: Besides the space added by `babel`?

Comment: Yes. I mean: I didn't find the right code to add it.

Comment: If you’re not using `babel`, you can do this with lines like `["r"] = { ["question"] = 9000 },` and `["d"] = { ["question"] = 900 },` and `["agrave"] = { ["question"] = 450 },` (the values are exaggerated to make the effect obvious), but that takes patience. And if you do use `babel`, it controls the spacing.

Comment: I don’t have time to inspect the innards of `babel`, but you may want to study, say, `.../texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/frenchb.lua`. And I always prefer using fonts by French designers for French texts; the results are better.

Comment: It seems that you know your job perfectly. I'm searching for a font which would be equivalent to Sabon or Bembo, but designed for French language. Could you please give me some suggestions? In this way, I wouldn't have to modify the fonts I use.

Comment: I love Henry and Louize from [205TF](https://www.205.tf/) and Le Monde Livre Classic from [Typofonderie](https://typofonderie.com/). I don’t have [Sabon Next](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/sabon-next/), but it’s the work of Jean François Porchez, of Typofonderie. Note that I’m not a mathematician; I can recognize a great text font but don’t know what would be needed if your article involves math.

Comment: Thank you! And what about Adobe Garamond Pro? Will I have to adjust font features?

Comment: Garamond Premier Pro has the same tight spacing as other Adobe fonts.

Comment: I finally choosed Adobe Garamond Pro and it works perfectly. Merci !