# Kerning with Lualatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, kerning

This is a recurring topic, but I haven't found a satisfactory and up-to-date answer. I apologize for any redundancy.

I'd like to use Hoefler Text within Linux/Tex Live. I installed the font as a system font. I load it with `Lualatex`.

Writing in French, Hoefler has some problems with properly kerning the apostrophe:

[image]

`L\mbox{'}exemple` is better:

[image]

However, this is not practical. Given that microtype's kerning is not available in Lualatex, how would you best solve the issue? Is this achievable through `\directlua`? Should I install the font to be used through `pdfTex`?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/599837

Comment: Thanks I could have spot this post. One last question if I may: how would you define the space between the L et the apostrophe as achieved with \mbox without defining the kerning for L?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand what you’re asking in your comment. Maybe I need more caffeine.

Comment: Do you use `babel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing, I realised that the problematic kerning was rather between the "L" et the apostrophe (I also sligthly corrected the "T"):

```
\directlua{fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature
  {
    name = "kern",
    type = "kern",
    data = {                        
    ["L"] = { ["quoteright"] = 300 },
    ["T"] = { ["quoteright"] = 100 },
    }, 
  }
}
```

Comment: Another useful reason why LuaLaTeX is awesome!