How to increase the space between letters and apostrophes?
I use Times Ten Paneuropean and I have to increase the space between some letters and apostrophes: d'A and l'A. How could I do that? This is my MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,Mapping=tex-text]{Times Ten W1G}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{A title}
 
d'Anytos, d’Athènes, l'Agora, l'Acropole.
 
\end{document}


This is an apostrophe, not a comma, I think.

since the example includes both commas and apostrophes, I've corrected this in your question to avoid confusion. please revert the change if you didn't want this.

What has Times Ten Pro to do with the code you present?

@egreg Nothing to do, but the fact that I don't think that a lot of people has it.

so most people won't be able to compile the code to reproduce the issue you want help with.

Please test the code you posted, it will stop on line 2 as setmainfont  is not defined

@cfr That's the reason why I did not mention Times Ten W1G first. Anyway, is there any trick to add some spacing between letters and apostrophes which could fit to any font?

The mechanisms you could use are completely dependent on the font technology so if using opentype and luatex is different to opentype and xetex and completely different to your original example with 8 bit tfm fonts

Have you tried applying the principles in your question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/599837 or at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/411846?

@Thérèse : Yes, I've just done it and it works!

by the way, this isn't letterspacing. but if you want a generic answer, always give an example using a standard font e.g. supplied with TeX Live.
