# Cabin font doesn't render properly apostrophe

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I'm using Cabin font with XeLaTeX. The [apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) is not render properly.

As you can see on the following screenshot, there is not enough space betweend `L` and `a`.

[image]

On this screenshot (with the default LaTeX font), there is no problem:

[image]

Is it possible to fix this?

MWE (use XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cabin}
\begin{document}
L'apostrophe
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I check `L’apost L'apost` on [fontsquirrel.com](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/cabin#testdrive), I'll get the same output for `’` and a little more space for `'`. This seems to be a problem related to the font itself.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218415/7883 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61759/7883.  Not a few fonts look OK for  English text but bad with French.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

It seems that it is very tightly spaced to following lowercase letters (1).
You can prevent the kerning with `\mbox` (2). I assume a word space is too much (3) or you could use the xetex inter-character token class to add an extra kern, here I set up a class for `'` and a class for lower case ascii letters
and inject a small kern if `'` is followed immediately by a letter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cabin}

\begin{document}
L'apostrophe

L\mbox{'}apostrophe

L' apostrophe

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\newXeTeXintercharclass\aposclass
\newXeTeXintercharclass\letterclass
\XeTeXcharclass`\'=\aposclass
\count0=`a
\loop
\XeTeXcharclass\count0=\letterclass
\advance\count0 1
\ifnum\count0<`z
\repeat
\count0=1

\XeTeXinterchartoks\aposclass\letterclass{\kern.1em}

L'apostrophe

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. The solution 3 is interesting. However, there are still little differences between a apostrophe with the normal font and with cabin and your code. For example the `'` is too close to the `L`. So a font who renders properly French should be prefered.

Comment: @ppr  I think it's essentially a bug in the font and the fix was only intended to be font-specific just to be enabled where cabin is being used.