# L'Circonflexe Accent --- How to Adjust Its Height

Tags: fonts, accents, french, height, textheight

With certain fonts (e.g., Cabin), I have noticed a difference in the relative positioning of certain accent marks---to the point where sometimes, it seems to me that an adjustment is in order.

Consider, for instance, the circumflex accent (^) in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cabin}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Huge

\textbf{S\^ur}
\vspace*{35pt}

\cabin
With Cabin font: \, S\^ur
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I adjust the height of the said accent mark so that (in this case) it appears closer to the associated letter? I am retyping an Introduction to a book in which the circumflex accent appears very close to the letter in the French component of the Introduction. Is there a general way to accomplish this height adjustment? Otherwise, is there a way to modify the height of the accent when using the Cabin font? Thank you.

Comment: That's a choice by the font designer.

Comment: Why aren't you using pre-composed glyphs? With a modern LaTeX engine (like `LuaLaTeX`) you could write `Sûr` directly, and the (accented) character in your document would be exactly what the font designer intended.

Comment: @egreg That I suppose is true; but if you consider, say, the apostrophe: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250233/cabin-font-doesnt-render-properly-apostrophe/250265#250265 there are method(s) to alter the font designer's prescription. I was hoping to learn of one here from the question I posed.