# How to Increase the Space Between a Letter and Its Apostrophe with Cabin

Tags: fonts, spacing, pdftex, apostrophe, cabin

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent How to slightly increase the spacing between a letter and Cabin's apostrophe?
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: I would like to ever-so-slightly increase the space between (in the case of this MWE) the letter *n* and the apostrophe. It seems to me, when using the Cabin font, that spacing is relatively small. How may I do this for all such words where an apostrophe immediately follows a letter?

I am compiling with `pdflatex`.

Thank you.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/250233 is related.

Comment: @Thérèse Yes; but the solution is for compiling with `xelatex`, It would not work for `pdflatex`. There's at least one other post I'm aware of with a similar `xelatex` solution, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\mbox{'}` as apostrophe for Cabin font.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent How to slightly increase the spacing between a letter and Cabin\mbox{'}s apostrophe?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Sebastiano for this helpful answer.

Comment: @mlchristians you are welcome.