# General Spacing Solution When Using Cabin Font, Csquotes, and Pdflatex

Tags: spacing, pdftex, csquotes, quotation, cabin

This post is related to the question asked in [How to Increase the Space Between a Letter and Its Apostrophe with Cabin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671708/how-to-increase-the-space-between-a-letter-and-its-apostrophe-with-cabin).

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent \enquote{When I asked him why nobody goes there anymore, he replied \enquote{because it's \textit{too} crowded.}}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

In the aforementioned post, it was suggested that to increase the space between a letter and its associated apostrophe when using the `cabin` font, one may simply, for example, do this: `it\mbox{'}s`, which seems to accomplish the task for the specific problem at hand.

On the other hand, how would one obtain the desired objective in the general case; that is, when using, say, nested quotes using `\enquote` commands?

More specifically, when compiling with `pdflatex`:

QUESTION: Is there, perhaps, a general macro that may be employed when using the `cabin` font to slightly increase the space between (i) the letter and the apostrophe *e.g.* in **it's**; and (ii) to increase the space between the closing single quote and the closing double quote, such as in, **it's *too* crowded'''**?

Thank you.

QUESTION:

Comment: the space between apostroph and s is a font "feature", so report it to the font maintainer. The space between quotes is a csquotes command and can e.g. be changed with `\makeatletter \AtBeginDocument{\def\csq@thequote@kern{0.2em}}`.

Comment: This doesn’t solve your problem, but it’s worth noting that the version of [Cabin](https://github.com/impallari/Cabin) in TeX Live is rather old.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Many thanks for pointing out the `\makeatletter \AtBeginDocument{\def\csq@thequote@kern{0.2em}}` fix, which takes care of the `enquote` dilemma.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you for your note regarding the version of `Cabin` in Tex Live.